# How to safely count dictionary keys in python

Tags: python, django

I'm writing a django application where I will get a dictionary from the user that can be of variable size. I want to have a limit for how big the dictionary can be, i.e. how many `(key, value)` pairs it can hold. I want it to be no bigger than 200. I suspect that if I do:

```
if len(user_dict)>200:
    raise ValidationError("dict has too many (key, value) pairs")
```

python will have to count the whole dict. If the dict is huge, because of a malicious user, this will eat unnecessary processing power. Or does the dict keep track of how many objects it holds, meaning `len(user_dict)` is a simple lookup operation? What is the best way to solve this problem?

I was thinking something like:

```
i=0
for key in user_dict.keys():
    i += 1
    if i>200:
        raise ValidationError("dict has too many (key, value) pairs")
```

Comment: If `user_dict` is a dictionary, then `len(..)` works in *O(1)* so constant time.

Comment: Willem, thank you, that answers my question.

Comment: As Willem says - the number of keys in a dictionary is stored as part of the object itself - it doesn't need to compute it. (same with the builtin `list`, `set`, `tuple` container types)

Comment: @AvinashRaj: noo... that is still *O(1)* but will be easily 200 times slower.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem so you mean `len(dict_)`  and for computing the first item `for i in dict_: break` will take the same time.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: `len(..)` works in constant time (and performs a lookup on a field). So that means that obtaining the `len(..)` of a dictionary with 100k elements, is the same as obtaining the `len(..)` of a dictionary with no elements at all (approximately, of course cache etc. can lead to small differences).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Or does the dict keep track of how many objects it holds, meaning `len(user_dict)` is a simple lookup operation?

A dictionary - given a serious interpreter implementation like CPython - indeed keeps track of the number of key-value pairs that are stored in the dictionary. So *if* `user_dict` is indeed a dictionary, then `len(user_dict)` works in *O(1)* and is very fast. The fact that it works in constant time also means that it makes no (theoretical) difference whether we calculate the `len(..)` of a `dict` object with 100k items, or none at all.

No iteration is necessary to count the number of objects. For instance the [CPython source code for the `dict` class has](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L1954):

> ```
> static Py_ssize_t
> dict_length(PyDictObject *mp)
> {
>     return mp->ma_used;
> }
> ```

So it returns the `ma_used` field of the dictionary object (which is thus a field containing the number of items in the dictionary).

This is also described in [this file](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/ICS-33/lectures/complexitypython.txt):

> ```
> Dictionaries: dict and defaultdict
>                                Complexity
> Operation     | Example      | Class         | Notes
> --------------+--------------+---------------+-------------------------------
> Index         | d[k]         | O(1)      |
> Store         | d[k] = v     | O(1)      |
> Length        | len(d)       | O(1)      |
> Delete        | del d[k]     | O(1)      |
> get/setdefault| d.method     | O(1)      |
> Pop           | d.pop(k)     | O(1)      |
> Pop item      | d.popitem()  | O(1)      |
> Clear         | d.clear()    | O(1)      | similar to s = {} or = dict()
> View          | d.keys()     | O(1)      | same for d.values()
>
> Construction  | dict(...)    | O(len(...))   | depends # (key,value) 2-tuples
>
> Iteration     | for k in d:  | O(N)          | all forms: keys, values, items
> ```

Comment: Very nice answer. Thanks